# Is it still possible to install PerfWatson for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perfwatson

A long while ago [Scott Hanselman talked about PerfWatson](https://www.hanselminutes.com/289/inside-visual-studio-performance-and-perfwatson-with-phil-price). I've finally decided to install this extension in Visual Studio, but the extension no longer appears to be available for public-consumption (perform either a search or click on the appropriate link on the [PerfWatson Monitor extension)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a3c888f2-40e0-4370-83e0-2952febf9e4f).

Is there an alternative to PerfWatson, or has it been completely phased out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The PerfWatson extension is now available](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fa85b17d-3df2-49b1-bee6-71527ffef441?SRC=Home), and was updated on May 24th. The first paragraph says:

> The Visual Studio team no longer collects PerfWatson reports for Visual Studio 2010. Your reports helped us to identify the issues affecting you most, and you can see improvements in Visual Studio 11 Beta. The PerfWatson extension is included in the VS11 Beta release.  If you would like to use PerfWatson to automatically report on any responsiveness issues you are encountering, please download and try out the VS11 Beta.

Looks like it's no longer valuable.

### Update July 2017

It appears that PerfWatson is available as [a Visual Studio Extension for 2012, 2013, 2015, and 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulHarrington.PerfWatsonMonitor-9621).

[Paul Harrington](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/paul%20harrington/) appears to be a software engineer at Microsoft, but no idea if the extension's purpose remains the same.